# Trying to transfer Object from one controller class to another

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I am trying to transfer an object from Controller A to Controller B, but whenever I try, it sets my object as null.
I have an object of called user in Controller B. Also in Controller B I have a method called public void setUser(). The full method is:
public void setUser(User user) {
this.user = user;
In Controller A, I do the following:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("B.fxml"));
loader.load();
ControllerB ctrl = loader.getController();
cntrl.setUser(user);
```

In Controller B I have this:

```
SalesAsso user;
public void setUser(SalesAsso user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

my controller B object is not null, but it still doesn't set my user as "user". I run the code, it It runs fine. but then when I try to manipulate that salesAsso object, the object is null and It won't let me do anything with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: So if did say SalesAssociateScreenController.setSalesAssociate(this.user);  would it fix the nullpointer error?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. What I needed to do was store the variable from controller a into a static variable of the same type in controller b. That let me manipulate the object in the controller b class!

Comment: hmm ... static sounds ... wrong .. you did read the referenced answer, didn't you :)

Comment: Yea I add. That did help transferring the object from one controller. But then after I transferred it. I referencedd it a static object that was already into my controller to that object. And then that let me manipulate the object with all the different methods and events

Comment: 99% of static fields are .. wrong, so most probably there's something fishy with the "static object that was already" :)

Comment: So do you think I should remove the static field?

Comment: yeah, in the longer run certainly .. depending on your time frame/experience you can mark it as problematic and come back to replace later - don't want to drive you along a road you might not yet ready to go right now :)